# Topology of decomposition of a space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

In [pg 121](https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/jeber_02/skripten/mainfile.pdf) of this notes, the author outlines a construction of gluing bundles. The scenario begins with

> Let $X= X_0 \cup X_1$ be union of two comapct spaces.  $A = X_0 \cap X_1$ **so** that $X = X_0 \bigsqcup X_1 /A$.

Why does $X$ have the same topology as $X_0 \sqcup X_1 /A$?

---

An open set in $X$ does map to an open set in RHS, but is the converse true?

---

Comment: Do you understand what they mean by $/A$? It's not minus $A$ it is a quotient map when you identify two points in $A$ as being equal.

Comment: Yes, I understand that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a surjection $X_0 \sqcup X_1 \to X$, which identify points in $A$. It induces a continuous bijection $(X_0 \sqcup X_1)/A \to X$ hence an homeomorphism since both spaces are compact.

Comment: I suppose this then requires $X$ to be Hausdorff?

Comment: No, I think the argument work without Hausdorff assumptions.

Comment: How would you prove its a closed map then? Or how does homeomorphism follows?

Comment: Ah sorry of course you need to identify compact and closed sets in $(X_0 \sqcup X_1)/A$. The argument might not work if the spaces are non-Hausdorff indeed, sorry about it.

Comment: @CL. Note that if the spaces are Hausdorff you can use the fact that any continuous bijection is necessarily an homeomorphism. So you don't even need to prove the continuity of the inverse.